# Mobile Image Issue in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm having issues with images "blowing" out of their frame on the mobile version of my site. Excuse my terms,  I'm not sure of the correct lingo.

An example:

[www.mountainobsession.com/pp-offsider-co](http://www.mountainobsession.com/pp-offsider-co)

Any tips for correcting this would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: for a quick and dirty fix, add `max-width: 100%;` to `img`

Answer (score 0):

Your images aren't responsive once you hit `600px`. You can simple add the following to your `img` tag:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px){
    .content-main img{
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Would this change it for all images on my site, as I am having issues with it on all posts? Also, what CSS file should this be placed in?

Comment: This would change for all images inside the .content-main tag. Your code didn't seem to have any other specific classes that would help with that. It seems like the responsive.css would be the correct place.